# what is grep -v -f /dev/null expected to do exactly?

Tags: grep

**Theory:** `grep -f somefile` or `grep --file=somefile` will find all lines that match one of the patterns listed in `somefile`. If `somefile` is empty, nothing will match. With `grep -v` you list lines that *do not* match.

**Bottom line:** `grep -f /dev/null` matches nothing and `grep -v -f /dev/null` matches everything.

**Experiment:** Now try it with

```
% echo blank | grep -f /dev/null
% echo bingo | grep -v -f /dev/null
bingo
```

**Outcomes:** Indeed I do get `bingo` (and only that) on one machine that has

```
unix1% grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

But **I do not get `bingo`** !?!? on another machine, this time with

```
unix2% grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
unix2% uname -rs
Darwin 14.0.0
```

**Question:** is there some leeway in the spec of `grep`? Some legalese that I missed? Or is `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` buggy? The sure thing is that I spent two hours finding what went wrong when porting my scripts from unix1 to unix2 ...

Comment: Behaviour is only specified if the file contains at least one line. So for an empty  file or a file that contains no newline characters, or files with NUL characters, or files with more than LINE_MAX between two newline characters, `grep` implementations may do what they like.

Comment: Really? The BSD man page says for -f: "if file is empty, nothing is matched" and for -v: "selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns". If nothing matches in the 1st case, they look like valid lines for -v.

Comment: I was referring to the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: He's right: *"A null pattern can be specified by **an empty line** in pattern_file."*

Comment: Why you try find the problem where it don't exist? Use `grep .` instead.

Comment: @Costas: In my application the file is generated automatically and it is sometimes empty but usually not. Please don't say that the problem "does not exist" to one of its victims.

Comment: @goldilocks: a file with one empty line is not an empty file with no line.

Comment: That's exactly S.C.'s point.  `/dev/null` **is not** a file with an empty line.  It has no empty lines.  The spec doesn't say anything about what that should mean (hence it is *unspecified*).

Comment: The BSD man page says for -f: "if file is empty, nothing is matched". I don't take that as unspecified.

Comment: @phs The BSD man page is not the POSIX specification. The POSIX spec says nothing about an empty file. Its description of `-f` says: _Read one or more patterns from the file named by the pathname pattern_file._ So there needs to be at least one pattern in the file.

Comment: OK, I understand what the POSIX spec says and does not say. Thanks to all. Now back to the main issue: does this make 2.5.1-FreeBSD grep right? It is not as intuitive & useful as GNU grep 2.20. And its man page adds to the obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GNU grep man page:

> ```
> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>        Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
>        contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
>        specified by POSIX.)
> -v, --invert-match
>        Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
>        is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

so `grep -f /dev/null` will match *nothing* and `grep -v -f /dev/null` will invert that and match *everything*.

I have access to a whole plethora of FreeBSD systems, but *all* of them have GNU grep installed because it is so much better (both for [speed](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) and features, though it does appear that [BSD grep is catching up](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep)).  There are still differences, e.g. in [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961891/logic-behind-word-boundary-difference-between-bsd-grep-and-gnu-grep).

I suspect this is a BSD grep bug, though perhaps the spec is ambiguous.  A note from that "catching up" link: BSD grep is basically an effort to get a more permissively licensed clone of GNU grep, which means it will always be "behind" on at least something.

If possible, I recommend installing GNU grep on those systems using BSD grep.

If you're just trying to make your code maximally portable, I suppose I'd follow up by asking why you're grepping for ~nothing.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  Maybe that's better to focus on.

Comment: 1.0E99 thanks for the supportive attitude. And indeed gnu grep works fine for me. What am I trying to achieve? I have a huge list of urls generated by crawling some web site. I also have a black list generated by another program. I want to extract from the first list using `grep -v -F -f black-list`. Since the black list is generated by a program, I do not know in advance if it is empty or not.

Comment: Ah.  Try this:  `command | ( [ -s black-list ] && grep -vFf black-list ] || cat )`.  This uses [short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) like the [`?:` ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to run `grep` only when there are blacklist items (the file `black-list` has non-zero size), otherwise just run `cat` as a passthrough.

Comment: Actually, that'll show the whole output if every line is blacklisted.  Use this instead: `command | ( if [ -s black-list ]; then grep -vFf blacklist; else cat; fi )`